# How to close Zebra Dialog using callback function?

Tags: jquery

How can i close the dialog on call back function. I have tried this but it not works. Below is my code.

```
$.Zebra_Dialog(“Please select a recrod”, {
         ‘type’: ‘warning’,
         ‘title’: ‘warning’,
         ‘buttons’:
         [
              {caption: 'OK', callback: function() {
                      this.close();
             }}
         ]
});
```

Comment: Do a console.log on `this` in your callback method.  I would be that it is something other than your zebra dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
var md=$.Zebra_Dialog(“Please select a recrod”, {
         ‘type’: ‘warning’,
         ‘title’: ‘warning’,
         ‘buttons’:
         [
              {caption: 'OK', callback: function() {
                      md.close();
             }}
         ]
});
```